# How do I access the ParentView in an event handler in a child view

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I would like to access the parentView from an event handler but when I click on the child view text I get an error that this.parentView is undefined ??  event.view.parentView does not work either.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script src="js/libs/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script src="js/libs/handlebars-1.0.0-rc.3.js"></script>
    <script src="js/libs/ember-1.0.0-rc.2.js"></script>
    <script>

        App = Ember.Application.create();

        App.ChildView = Ember.View.extend({
           template : Ember.Handlebars.compile("Child View {{ view.elementId }} parent={{ view.parentView.elementId}}"),
           click:function(event){
               alert("parent="+this.parentView.elementId);
           }
        });


        App.TopView = Ember.View.extend({
           template : Ember.Handlebars.compile("Top View {{ view.elementId }} {{ view App.ChildView }}")
        });

        var v = App.TopView.create();
        v.append();
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ember, currently, we have to use [`get`](http://emberjs.com/api/#method_get) and [`set`](http://emberjs.com/api/#method_set) methods fore reading or assigning values to properties.

So you should do:

```
App.ChildView = Ember.View.extend({
    template : Ember.Handlebars.compile(
        "Child View {{view.elementId}} parent={{ view.parentView.elementId}}"
    ),
    click:function(event){
        alert("parent=" + this.get('parentView.elementId');
    }
});
```

Comment: perfect.. thanks a lot. been scratching my head for a while with that one.

Comment: unfortunately reading and fully comprehending are not the same .. for me at least :-/